# Getting error when set values ​into getRange() - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Objective**

Get the rows where the dates in column A are within the range of this current month and year. In the rows that coincide in month and year with the current date, the value "yes" will be placed in the cell of column O (col. 15 - Array 14). The non-matching rows will be placed the value "no" in the cell of column 0 (col.15). Finally, checkboxes will be created for the entire column O (col.15), and depending on the value of the cell, the checkboxes will be marked or not.

**Problem**

I am getting an error "Exception: Service error: Spreadsheets" in the line of code `dataRange.setValues(dataValues);` And I don't know why or how to fix it.
This error in GAS is not explained any more. I have looked for solutions online but despite following the instructions, I can not solve this.

**My code**

```
function thisMonth() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(' Todos los eventos');
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
    
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1, lastCol); 
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

    const now = new Date();
    const month = now.getMonth();
    const year = now.getFullYear();

    dataValues.forEach((fila)=> {
      var dateColA = new Date(fila[0]);    
      if ( month == dateColA.getMonth() && year == dateColA.getFullYear() ){
        fila[14] = 'yes';
        Logger.log(dateColA + ' - ' + fila[3]);        
      } else { 
        fila[14] = 'no';
      }
    })

    dataRange.setValues(dataValues);
    sheet.getRange(2, 15, lastRow -1, 1).insertCheckboxes('yes');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `lastCol` equals 15, column O?  If its blank then your data range would be only up N or 14 columns and `file[14]` would add a column to the `dataValues` array.

Comment: @TheWizEd In my sheet I have 16 columns in total (A to P) with data. But I have to compare the dates in column A with the current date, and depending on the results, add one text or another text in the cells of column O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works with a small sample sheet I made. Not sure about your exact error but I've heard it could be related to reaching some kind of limit when handling Sheet data. With that in mind, you should try to optimize it. You don't need to get the entire x-rows by 15-columns range and manipulate it then completely rewrite it to the Sheet, when all you want is to edit the "O" column.

I suggest you instead try to optimize your code to only get the values from column "A" to compare the dates, then create a local array to build the "O" column and then set the values to just that column. Here's a sample that worked for me:

```
function thisMonth() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(' Todos los eventos');
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
    
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1);
    var checkboxRange = sheet.getRange(2, 15, lastRow -1)
    var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
    var checkboxValues = []

    const now = new Date();
    const month = now.getMonth();
    const year = now.getFullYear();

    for (i = 0; i<dataValues.length; i++){
      if (dataValues[i][0].getMonth()==month && dataValues[i][0].getFullYear()==year){
        checkboxValues.push(["yes"])
        }else{
        checkboxValues.push(["no"])
      }
    }

    checkboxRange.setValues(checkboxValues);
    sheet.getRange(2, 15, lastRow -1).insertCheckboxes('yes');
}
```

Comment: Hello Daniel! That's weird. I have another similar function and it worked perfectly for me, but with this new function that I created there was no way and I was worried. In fact, your answer and your code are much more logical than mine! As you say, it is more optimized and clean. I had not thought of such a solution. In these cases it shows that I am a total novice hehehe. Your code works perfectly and I have learned new things thanks to your explanation, for which I am very grateful!